# Android - ListViews broken after creating a BaseListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some classes that used to inherit from ListActivity directly.  Everything worked.  Now I am inheriting from BaseListActivity which inherits from ListActivity.

Here is BaseListActivity:

```
public class BaseListActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);      
    {
        Button home_header = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_header);
        Button questions_header = (Button)findViewById(R.id.questions_header);

        home_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                   
              Intent myIntent = new Intent( BaseListActivity.this , ProblemioActivity.class);
              BaseListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });                 

        questions_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {  
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                   
              Intent myIntent = new Intent( BaseListActivity.this , MyQuestionsActivity.class);
              BaseListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });         
}
}
```

It basically adds a header to the page. But now none of the lists get rendered and there are no exceptions.

Any idea what else I had to do to make it work?

Here is how I changed my original layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >    


<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_label"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading your questions..."
    />     

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>
```

Here is my onCreate

```
public class MyQuestionsActivity extends BaseListActivity
{
    ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter;     

    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList <Question>( );        

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.users_questions);

    Question q = new Question ();
    q.setQuestion( "" );

    questions.add(q);       

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions);
```

Right now I have this in my BaseListActivity

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);      
    {
```

I just tried this:

```
public class BaseListActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);      
    {
        setListAdapter(this.getListAdapter());
```

but it didn't quite work :(

Comment: Where you added these buttons  home_header and questions_header?

Comment: @DheereshSingh I just updated the original question with my layout.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/08/08/custom-android-listactivity.aspx

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

is there this line in  onCreate .........
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: I just added my onCreate to the original question.

Comment: I have that super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); but I am not sure what might be wrong with using it, or what it really should be.

Comment: Oh I think I get it, I also need to reference the listadapter in the BaseListView

Comment: take a look at the bottom of my question.  I think I posted where the inconsistency is.

Comment: setListAdapter(this.adapter); i this line is there ?

Comment: No not there...let me try that!

Comment: just need to confirm, are you able to see the buttons ?

Comment: yes I am able to see the buttons.  The header renders perfectly.  What doesn't render is the list of things in the content area of the screen :)

Comment: I just updated my question with that I just tried....does it look off?  Still not working.

Comment: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions); after this line use setListAdapter(this.adapter);

Comment: Yes I have that line in the very bottom class.  But something isn't right with the BaseListActivity class.  Let me explain..

Comment: My structure is like this:  SomeClass extends BaseListActivity and BaseListActivity extends ListActivity.

Comment: The line you posted is in my SomeClass but I am not sure how to adjust the BaseListActivity to make all the SomeClass have their lists rendered.

Comment: you need to set the your adapter having data at-least once... so plese try it in your MyQuestionsActivity  because there you crated the adapter..

Comment: yeah, I have it there.  That part was actually working.  It only stopped working when I added the BaseListActivity :) so the MyQuestionsActivity was setting the list prior to this, and is still trying to set the list.